# Kivy ButtonBehavior is not defined error

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am running Ubuntu 14.1 with kivy 1.9.0 python 2.7

I am attempting to write a small program that utilizes ButtonBehavior but it keeps saying the name is not defined during application startup. I have another program that uses ButtonBehavior and it boots up just fine. Actually I copied that import directly from the file that works and i still keep getting the same error. 
I tried uninstalling kivy and re-installing but it has not worked. Spellings and everything just for some reason it will not load for this app.

Here is the traceback:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <3.0 Mesa 10.1.3>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel Open Source Technology Center>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mesa DRI Intel(R) Broadwell >
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.30>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "uf.py", line 27, in <module>
     class TestIcon(ButtonBehavior, Image):
 NameError: name 'ButtonBehavior' is not defined
```

```
import kivy
import subprocess

from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.clock import Clock
import  ufhubtest as uf
import time

PORT_NUM = 3
POWER_OFF_SECS = 3
POWER_ON__SECS = 3

class ListViewLabel(Label):
    pass

class PassFail(Label):
    pass

class TestIcon(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    self.pf = ObjectProperty()
    self.ti = ObjectProperty()

    self.passcount = 0
    self.failcount = 0
    self.hubdev = None

    def find_hub(self):
        self.hubdev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0424, idProduct=0x2640)

        if self.hubdev is None:
            self.pf.text= "No Hub found for port power control"
            time.sleep = 2
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            Clock.schedule_once(self.run_test)

    def run_test(self):

        #Clock.unschedule(self.run_test)

        while True:
            try:
                uf.port_power1(hubdev, PORT_NUM, False)
                time.sleep(POWER_OFF_SECS)
                uf.port_power1(hubdev, PORT_NUM, True)
                time.sleep(POWER_ON__SECS)
                dhub = usb.core.find(idVendor=DUT_VID, idProduct=DUT_PID)
                if dhub is not None:
                    passcount = passcount + 1
                    print "%s: Pass:%d Fail:%d" % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), passcount, failcount)
                else:
                    failcount = failcount + 1
                    print "%s: Pass:%d Fail:%d -- Hub not found" % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), passcount, failcount)

            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                print "Interrupted"
                break

class UfApp(App):
        pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    UfApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In class `MainLayout`, you use `self.` outside of a function. Read errors more carefully.

Comment: I removed the "self"s and i am still getting the error.

Comment: @mri3 You haven't imported Image class and some other classes/modules.